# Laravel error message if email is not registered during password reset (upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I recently upgraded my laravel 5.6 project to laravel 5.7, I am experiencing an issue right after I upraded to laravel 5.7. when I enter a registered email, password reset email is sent successfully and the correponding session status message is displayed in the page but when I enter a non registered email the  `$errors->first('email')` displays **passwords.user** instead if displaying **We can't find a user with that e-mail address.** (laravel predefined error message).

**How do I solve this problem???**

**auth/passwords/email.blade.php:**

```
<form action="{{ route('password.email') }}" class="forgot_Form text-center" method="POST" id="forgot_password">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="email" class="form-control email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="label label-danger">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn">
                Send Password Reset Link
            </button>
        </form>
```

**ForgotPasswordController.php:**

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

*I am using laravel built-in authentication*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason Laravel have changed the password reset validation errors to make use of localization and translations.

To solve your issue:

1. Create a file named `passwords.php` within `resources/lang/en` directory.
2. Within this file you can return an array of any key that comes after the `passwords.` in the validation message.

For example:

```
return [
    'user' => 'We can't find a user with that e-mail address.'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting the validation method provided by the trait `SendsPasswordResetEmails`:

In `ForgotPasswordController`, add this method:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, 
        [
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ],[
            'email.email' => '<Your custom email error message>',
            'email.required' => '<Your custom email error message>'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: The above displayed error message is after the successful validation of input field and after checking users table that the email column does not contain that email.
Please read the question carefully

Answer (score 0):

**In login controller put the following code :**

```
 public function verifyUser($token)
    {
        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
        if(isset($verifyUser) ){

            if(!$user->verified) {
                $verifyUser->verified = 1;
                $verifyUser->save();

                $status = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
            }else{
                $status = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/login')->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
        }

        return redirect('/login')->with('status', $status);
    }
```